# How do I create a web socket client in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I need post some data to websocket server from my rails application. Meaning, I have made a Rails web service where I need to post some data to a web socket server when some API calls are made. Is there any pre-built library which provide to create a web socket client easily in Rails?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby client and server: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket

Also: https://github.com/mplatov/ruby-websocket-client

Comment: Is there anything to do with websocket version? b'coz when I data is transmitting properly but it is not published to all connections. Suppose one ruby-client is connected to em-websocket server and another html5 websocket client is also connected to em-websocket server. So when I transmit data from my server it should publish that data to all coonections. But it is transmiting only to ruby-client. I have checked header and there is difference of websocket version.